# Hover not click and have a lightBox appear with an image in it

Tags: jquery

I have been slaving over this for hours now. I need a lightbox to popup when I hover (not click) over a word in a paragraph. I have been trying different jquery plugins but none of them work unless I make the word a link and click it.

I have something like this

```
<p>I am a yellow dog, drinking a spotted cow.<p>
```

When I hover my mouse over the word "dog" a lightbox comes up and displays a picture of a dog in it until I leave the word. When I hover over "cow" a lightbox comes up with an image of a cow in it until I my mouse isnt on the word "cow" anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sort of a hack but might be able to meet your needs.

given the following markup:

```
<p>I am a yellow <span class="test">dog</span>, drinking a spotted cow.<p>
```

What we do is setup fancy box as normal.

```
$(".test").fancybox({
    href: "http://"
});

$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
    $("#fancybox-overlay").remove(); //remove the overlay so you can close when hover off.
}, function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/trnZS/2/).

Comment: when i hover over dog in the jsfiddle link nothing is happening

Comment: where do you get the images the css file is using from jsfiddle?

Comment: Information about fancybox can be found at http://fancybox.net/ Was that something like you were looking for?

Comment: I went there, and downloaded the zip file. Found the images in there added them here: App_Themes/Theme1/ folder. Then modified the css to point to the Theme1 folder like this  background: url(App_Themes/Theme1/fancybox.png) but I still dont see the fancybox around the image. Am I refenencing the images wrong in the css?

Comment: If you are using IE I believe they use custom filters to handle the transparency.  Look for `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=)`  When I used fancy box I just unzipped everything to the root of my application so I didn't need to alter any paths to png files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something i have done a while ago. Note the javascript resources on the left that.

http://jsfiddle.net/shrage/N8dKW/

When you hover on a link it can make an asynch call to launch some content for the server, it will fill in the light box with this content. 
When you move outside the link "AND" the box it will disappear.

When you "click" inside the box it will stay visible until you "click outside" the box.